# How to prevent sending custom value to CORS disabled API?

Tags: javascript, api, browser, cors, client-side

I get a photo(image file) from my user. I can access to their camera and they will take a photo and send that photo for me. Codes are written in JavaScript.

In my API, CORS is disabled and only requests from my site are valid. 
I want to **be sure that photo which i will get it, is a photo that is taken via camera**(codes are written in JS).
I want to get a image from API endpoint. That value is get from user camera and will be send via ajax request.

Can user send custom value to API if CORS is disabled?

I know that client side user can access JS codes via browser inspector, but **can user change JS codes and send custom value to CORS disabled API**?

Answer (score 0):

A user can send whatever they want to your HTTP endpoint.

HTTP endpoints are public. You have no control over what is sent to them.

A user could manually construct an HTTP request (e.g. with a tool like Postman or any programming language) and send whatever data they like without involving a browser at all.

Comment: Yes, but CORS is disabled and requests from origin site are valid only.User can't change origin site in Postman, can?

Comment: @ivahidmontazer — They don't need to. Postman isn't a lump of JS running on a random page that the browser has loaded. The same origin policy doesn't apply to it in the first place. The fact that CORS doesn't tell it to ignore the same origin policy therefore doesn't matter.

Comment: I know that a CORS disabled API isn't accessible from any client program or etc except origin site.

Comment: You're wrong. The Same Origin Policy (which CORS can tell browsers to relax) applies only to JS embedded in a webpage on a different origin. If that wasn't the case then (for example) any website which didn't grant permission with CORS would not be accessible to a web browser for normal display of a web page.

Comment: You mean that when CORS is disabled, only JS requests will be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

Any *client* (it doesn't even need to be a browser) can send *arbitrary* values to your API. It does not need to be a photo taken from the camera, it does not even need to be a photo at all. And you cannot prevent that, or force a browser to do anything. That includes preventing savy users from messing with your JS code.

[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is a client-side security measure implemented in many clients that prevents js code on other domains from accessing your API with the user's credentials. It does not help you here.